# How to get rid of the error: "Data source name not found and no default driver specified" in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, odbc

I was trying to built a asp.net web app with the connection string defined in the webconfig file. When I try to debug I am getting the following exception:

> ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

The connection string looks like this:

> connectionString="Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};server=XX.XX.XX.XX;port=3306;database=db_name;user=username;pwd=pass;option=3;" providerName="System.Data.Odbc"/>

The driver is installed and I can see it listed in the 'ODBC Data Source Administrator'.

I tried changing the build configuration to 'Any CPU', still it failed.

Can somebody help me out to figure whats going on here??

Thanks,

Uday

Comment: Can you write a test that yields the same exception without going through your web app?

Comment: The name of the driver in the ODBC Data Administrator is exactly : "MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver" ?

Comment: just want to add that the same connection string works with a console app!!

Comment: @aleroot yes it is exactly "MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver"

Comment: @AustinSalonen can you please explain what do you mean?

Comment: Are you on a x64 operating system ?

Comment: I noticed there's 32-bit and 64-bit versions of the MySQL ODBC driver. Maybe the console app is using the one you have installed, and the web-app is looking for the other architecture? Also, why use the ODBC driver instead of the native .NET connector?

Comment: Its working now!! I installed the 32bit MySQL driver and it worked. I guess no matter what my build configuration is, my app is looking for 32bit driver. But how come my console app work and not the web app?

Comment: The comment about it working in a console app effectively answers my question -- I wanted to confirm that it worked _somewhere else_.  Now that you have a console app, can you run that same app on your web server (safely)?

Comment: @Inerdia there is no specific reason for that! May be I will try the .NET connector.

Comment: @aleroot yes I am using x64 OS.

Comment: @AustinSalonen I am testing both on the same dev machine.

Comment: @Uday The .NET code is in and of itself not architecture-specific. So whether a .exe runs in 32-bit or 64-bit mode is a matter of which .NET runtime you use to "interpret" it. My guess is that the development server that runs ASP.NET apps from Visual Studio always runs in 32-bit mode regardless of how your VS project is set up.

Comment: @Inerdia if that is the case, can you please let me know where can I configure VS to run in 64-bit mode?

Comment: Also if it is indeed the .Net runtime is the issue...how come my console app work fine?

Comment: @Uday On 64-bit Windows, you have both the 32-bit and the 64-bit runtime installed – the console app was probably running with the 64-bit runtime. I'm afraid I don't know how you can run VS or the ASP.NET development server in 64-bit mode, or whether that's even possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have installed the x64 version of the ODBC driver you can use it compiling the executable as default (both CPU) otherwise you have to compile the executable as x86 only and use the x86-32 driver.

Keep in mind that by default on x64 os an application compiled as both CPU (x64 and x86) will use the 64bit version of the driver, this means that if you install the 32bit version of the ODBC driver and compile the executable as Both CPU or x64 you will get the error, so you have to compile the application only x86.

Comment: actually I knew this and thats what surprised me when my app worked after installing 32bit driver. I compiled the app just for x64 and still it failed!

Answer (score 0):

You could configure VS to use IIS instead of the internal one, plus you would get more experience configuring IIS correctly for your web app (i.e. Windows Server 2k8 R2 has pretty drastic configuration/security differences than previous versions).  If you configure your AppPool to run under 64 bit then your code should also run in 64 bit mode.